# Shortest Path Algorithm with a Double Weighted Graph

Tags: c++, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I have a directed graph with two weights between vertices, time and cost. The goal is to minimize time while keeping the cost under a maximum value given by the user. I was told to modify the Bellman-Ford algorithm by maintaining an ordered list based on cost instead of a single distance for each vertex of the graph. I am able to correctly implement the Bellman-Ford algorithm when only considering time as a factor, however what modifications to the algorithm do I need to keep cost under a maximum value as well?

Comment: That's nice, but what is your question?  Please read [ask].

Comment: @RichardCritten sorry, edited.

Comment: I think it might be more useful to have the user specify a value for their time; in the simple mode where it’s linear, you could just combine the time and money costs.  (Not that you necessarily get to change the requirements!)